# Smartsheet Cell History check

Tags: python, date, smartsheet-api

My goal is to pull a cell's history if it was modified after a user specified date. However, since the cell history call is so big, I don't really want to request the entire cell history until after I check the dates.  This is my code at current.

```
#get the cell history
action = smartsheet.Cells.get_cell_history(
    this_sheet.id,
    row.id,
    this_sheet.columns[c].id,
    include_all=True
    )

revisions = action.data


for rev in revisions:
    if rev.modified_at > date_of_interest:                
       ## print out information from this specific revision
```

I'd really like to do the date comparison prior to the call for the cell history or at least not call the entire cell history before I know that the information is going to be of interest. Surely there is a better way to do this. Thoughts?

Comment: Beth, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [GET sheet](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-sheet) request first and use that to see the last modified dates of the rows. For rows that are last modified based on your given date. Then you'll know it is worth getting the cell history. This would work if you are looking for data that was modified recently. If you are looking for older data you would need to get the cell history.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work. The row history doesn't align to the cell history. When I print the row modified_at, I get null for everything. When I print the cell modified_at, I get all kinds of date information.

Comment: The row modified data will be based on the last time any cell in that row was edited. I guess it depends on how far you are looking to go back in the cell history. If you are looking to take a given date from several weeks in the past and see the cell history you'll need to make the cell history call and check if data was entered then. You could look into a way to store that info for later lookups to know if data existed in the cell and if it is worth making the cell history request.

Comment: I agree in theory. However, my experience is that the row object prints NULL for all dates (Created, modified, etc). I have no idea why.

Comment: Sorry that it has taken me so long to reply on here. Though there isn't a method to check for if a specific cell has been modified during a certain date range I'd still like to help see why you get those NULL values. Could you write into api@smartsheet.com with an example request? I can help you more directly there if you'd like.